# Entity Framework Database First Property Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using EF database first and with MVC.

I'm wanting to add some validation on a property to compare its old value to its new one and report a validation error to the MVC ModelState if there is a problem.

This would be easy enough using code first and validating using 'set' on the property. However I can't do this using database first because its auto generated.

I've looked at using IValidatableObject and the validate() method however by then the value has already been changed on the property so I can't see the old one anymore to compare to.

Short of creating a method to pass the new value into first to check it, I can't think of another way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Just because it's auto-generated doesn't mean that you can't edit the POCOs after the fact. Even then, you could always just use a view model instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not the ideal and this has started illustrating some of the weaknesses in Model and DB first but here's how I ended up doing it.

I decided to change the property in my model so that set was private and then create a separate method in the partial class to set the value. The validation is then all done in that method.

Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a new value to an old value then you are going to have to grab the values from the database first (before updating) and compare them:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(MyObject myObject)
{
    var oldObject = db.Objects.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == myObject.Id);
    //Compare oldObject.Value to myObject.Value
}
```

You could still use `IValidatebleObject` and pass in the objects that you need to keep that logic outside the controller.